# Computing variables ONCE in tf loss function using y_pred shape

Tags: python, tensorflow

I created a custom Loss.
This function creates MANY matrices whose size depends on the total classes.

**Option 1:**
At first I created them using the last value of the shape of the input (`y_pred.shape[-1]`).
I then compute all the matrices, however, this makes the loss take a lot of time to compute. This can be done just once.

**Option 2:**
So I do it at the `__init__`, the problem is that I need to give the `classes` parameter at the constructor, which is an innecessary restriction if you ask me.

**Option 3:** (does not work).
I use the `@property` decorator to compute it only once, and then just get it. This looks something like this

```
    @property
    def classes(self):
        if self._classes is None:
            raise ValueError("classes was not yet initialized")
        return self._classes

    @classes.setter
    def classes(self, value):
        if self._classes is None:
            self._classes = value
        else:
            assert self._classes == value

    @property
    def mat_1(self):
        if self._mat_1 is None:
            ... # very big matrix
        return self._mat_1

    @property
    def mat_2(self):
        ... # another big matrix
```

This solution gave me an error:

```
TypeError: <tf.Tensor> is out of scope and cannot be used here. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
Please see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values for more information.
The tensor <tf.Tensor> cannot be accessed from here, because it was defined in FuncGraph(name=train_function, id=...), which is out of scope.
```

Going to the [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values), I understand that I am doing a tensor leak.

**My question**:

How can I init the matrices only once without giving the classes parameter to init but rather take it from `y_pred`?